# Show a specific process dialog in petrel?

Tags: dialog, ocean, petrel

I want to show a specified dialog under simulation category like "Developement Strategy" and do something after its "OK" click. Is there a way to show a native petrel process window?
I can see some class and interfaces in "**Slb.Ocean.Petrel.UI**" like *DialogBuilder* , *DialogPage*, *IDialogPageFactory*, *IDialogPage*...but I can't use them, even I don't know if they supply my required objects.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to create a Workstep (Slb.Ocean.Petrel.Workflow). The Ocean wizard lets offers a quick start. It creates optionally a process wrapper for you, which is the item showing up in the process tree.

Once you got familiar with the concepts, you can evolve the simplistic initial implementation by using the WorkflowEditorUIFactory. Check the namespace documentation in the Ocean documentation for more details.

IProcessDiagram offers different Add methods for your custom Process to enable custom positioning in the tree node sequence.

Comment: actually not! I know how to create a workstep or a process. I just want to load an embedded process like what I'd write("Developement Strategy") somewhere in my code. assume I have a GUI for my workstep and it has a Button Control. I want to load "Developement strategy" window when I click that button!

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically show a particular process dialog using `DialogBuilder.ShowSettings(object)` and passing the `Process` instance. This is typically used by a plug-in to launch its own process dialog, but it's possible to obtain a reference to the instance of a native `Process` by name using `FindProcess(string)`. This is, of course, a very fragile approach:

```
Process p = PetrelSystem.ProcessDiagram.FindProcess("Development strategy");
PetrelSystem.DialogBuilder.ShowSettings(p);
```

It would need a lot of error handling, not just to guard against changes to the process name, but also to handle the case where an exclusive process dialog is already open.

However, this will still only launch the dialog. There is no way to know if/when the user clicks the OK button. Petrel processes are typically stand-alone pieces of functionality, and any kind of chaining is generally supported by creating workflows.

Comment: I used this method, but no new window for strategy was presented, because the main page which is a process itself, is open when I call PetrelSystem.DialogBuilder.ShowSettings(p), nevertheles the process is been created successfully as a native process. can you help me to do the error handling you pointed it.

Comment: I can show the desired process using this statement, but I have to close my written process programmatically before the new one show itself... is there a way to show the new native process beside my process. if not, is there a way to re-open and show my closed process again?

Comment: Eventually this will be possible, but many of the Processes still need to be updated to handle having more than one dialog open at the same time. Take a look at `Process.ExclusivityCore` if your Process dialog doesn't need this restriction. Unfortunately, this will only help if "Development strategy" has already been updated to support non-exclusive behavior.

Comment: I couldn't find "Process.ExclusivityCore", where is this method or property?! how can I update a native process to support non-exclusive behavior? Is it possible for you to give me an example for this purpose?

Comment: Which version of Petrel are you building against? ExclusivityCore is fairly recent. Either 2013 or 2014. Most of the built-in processes have not been updated to non-exclusive, as that is ongoing work by the Petrel team. It's unfortunately just a matter of waiting at this point.